# Pointing to first field after validation

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a webpage which has check-boxes, input fields, dropdowns etc.,

Mandatory conditions are checked using javascript. If anyone fails to fill these fields and press next button validation errors popup.

Now what I want to achieve is when someone fails to enter information in the mandatory fields, the cursor should go to the first field which caused the error.

Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: you could loop through each filed and then on the first empty one set focus. as well as display an empty field result.

Comment: Yes, use `.focus()`. Please show us your code (validation & popup) so we can tell you how to get the first input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class (something like `input-error`) for every invalid field. Then use something like:

```
var errors = document.querySelectorAll(".input-error");
if (errors.length > 0) {
    errors[0].focus();
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/NtHzV/1/

It really all depends on the structure of your code, how you're validating, what you're actually doing with validation, and what your HTML is.

At the same time, if you're doing something similar to my example, you might as well keep track of the first input with an error, then `focus()` it at the end of validation. Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NtHzV/2/

**UPDATE:**

Bergi pointed out that `querySelector` might as well be used (instead of `querySelectorAll`) because you're only looking for the first input with errors. So here's an update:

```
var error_input = input_area.querySelector(".input-error");
if (error_input !== null) {
    error_input.focus();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NtHzV/3/

Here's specs on `querySelector`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.querySelector - Note that < IE8 does not support it.

The use of `".input-error"` is because that is the CSS class selector, and will find the first (if any) element in a specific area with the class "input-error".

Comment: @Bergi: how else would you get the first one?

Comment: `document.querySelector()`?

Comment: Before I saw your comments, I was editing with another option. To me, the reason I queried is for the case where things are separated such that the validation occurs in its own function or something that can't be controlled. **EDIT:** Didn't realize what you were specifically referring to :)

Comment: @Bergi Well crap. I always forget about that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This line will focus the page on the element you specify.  You should be able to implement this into your validation checks to focus on the bad elements.

`document.getElementById("ID_Of_bad_field").focus();`